# Putting objects of one class in array of other class

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object

I'm stuck in creating an array that must contain objects of different class, for example I've already created Objects of class `Student`:

```
Student* student11 = new Student("Vince", "Vaughn", "7-th Avenue", "New York", "783-945-90-28", 49);
Student* student12 = new Student("Vince", "Mcmahon", "Beverly Hills", "Los Angeles", "874-940-42-12", 47);
Student* student13 = new Student("Stone Cold", "Steve Austin", "Dallas", "Texas", "385-421-47-95", 34);
```

Then I created an object of class `Teacher`:

```
Teacher* teacher1 = new Teacher("Dave", "Bautista", "Washington", "Washington DC", "943-244-93-12", 31);
```

So the task is to put created objects of `Student` class in array that belongs to other class `Course`. And do the same thing with object of class `Teacher`.

Comment: do they inherit from a common base? If not I believe you misunderstood your task, because it is possible (see answer) but requires rather advanced stuff

Comment: or is it possible that there is a small misunderstadning and when you write " put created objects of Student class in array that belongs to other class Course" you actually mean that `Course` has two arrays as member, one for students and one for teachers?

Comment: Yeah the second variant is correct,thats exactly what i need to do!

Comment: in that case please try to clarify your question. Show what you tried and explain where you got stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are homogeneous: There is a single element type, and all elements of an array are of that same type. It is not possible to have elements of multiple types in an array.

If classes are related through inheritance, then it is possible to store pointers to base class sub objects, which may be the base of different derived types.

Another approach is to use a tagged union as the element type. `std::variant` is an implementation of tagged union provided by the standard library. Such type uses "type erasure" technique to store an object from a closed set of types.